# debian - cannot find interfaces

Tags: drivers, internet, debian

Debian can only find wlan interface for my computer where I had downloaded drivers for him. What should I install to provide other drivers? What is the packege?

Comment: What is teh device?

Comment: mine is zd1121, but there are drivers. I need other drivers for all.

Comment: Well, without knowing what device it is, I can't look up the package. Try running `dmesg` or `lspci`.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't quiet understand which devices you need drivers for, but you can start from here.

First make sure you have `contrib` and `non-free` areas added to your /etc/apt/sources.list for example:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian distribution main contrib non-free
```

where distribution is one of stable, squeeze, testing, wheezy, unstable, whichever one you track.

Then install package `firmware-linux` which should also install `firmware-linux-free` and `firmware-linux-nonfree`. Log out or reboot and see if your devices are recognized.

If not, it's best to search Debian package archive for the specific device firmware. You can do it via terminal command `apt-cache search <search_term>` or online at http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages